# Improper plotly graphs in r

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, graph, plotly

I was trying to implement a gapminder example in R using the plotly package from [here](https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/key-frame-animations.html)
which completely worked fine, but when I tried changing the data (here I used my own data set) and it shrank the values on Y-axis of the graph.
Here is the code

```
 library(gapminder)
    library(plotly)
    library(ggplot2)
    gg <- ggplot(gapminder_test, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, color = continent)) +
      geom_point(aes(size = pop, frame = year, ids = country)) +
      scale_x_log10()
    ggplotly(gg)
```

this is how the graph looks like
[image]
As you can see here on Y-axis the values have been shrunk off, how can I make it proper like a similar of gapminder

Comment: Without knowing the changes you applied to your data set `gapminder_test` very difficult to diagnose. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: The data is quite big to be reproduced, so I thought it to share it online, `dput` wouldn't also help.

Comment: just double-check if **lifeExp** is numerical

Comment: @MLavoie I don't know, it might sound strange, but when I took the input from an excel file its working fine, previously the input was from csv file

Comment: when you read gapminder_test what is the str()?

Comment: `> str(gapminder_test)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2025 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ country  : chr  "Shimla" "Shimla" "Shimla" "Shimla" ...
 $ year     : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ pop      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ continent: chr  "Tier II" "Tier II" "Tier II" "Tier II" ...
 $ lifeExp  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ gdpPercap: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your file and imported it. To avoid the `lifeExp` column being coerced into a factor because of the blanks (empty cells in your Excel file) you can use `na.strings = "N/A"`

```
gapminder_test <- read.csv("gapminderData_share.csv", na.strings = "N/A")
```

If already imported, as MLavoie pointed out, coerce it to numeric with `as.numeric`:

```
gapminder_test$lifeExp <- as.numeric(gapminder_test$lifeExp)
gg <- ggplot(gapminder_test, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, color = continent)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = pop, frame = year, ids = country)) +
  scale_x_log10()
ggplotly(gg)
```

Chart and animation look fine:

[image]

Comment: How do you scale the Y-axis, In your graph its showing(0,200,400,600) whereas in my graph its shows (5000,10000) ??

Comment: I did not tweak the axis scales. I read the file you posted. Maybe the comma separator is not right. But there is something definitely wrong in the data: in both life expectancy (above 100) and GDP. Once you solve it, the code should produce the right plot.